# Why does a holomorphic function, f, having a zero in the unit disc mean that its image contains the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

While working on a problem I have shown that a non-constant holomorphic function f, where |f(z)|=1 when |z|=1, has a zero. By making some trivial changes to the proof for that I am able to show that the zero is in the unit disc. Apparently this suffices for showing that the image of f contains the unit disc. Why?

Comment: I don't agree. $\frac{e^z-1}2$ has a zero at zero, but its image does not contain $-1/2$. What other conditions do you have on your function $f$?

Comment: I added them as an edit to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is a nonconstant holomorphic function on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk such that $|f(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$. You have proved that every such function must have a zero inside the unit disk. Let $w \in \mathbb{D}$, and apply this to
$$g(z):=\frac{f(z)-w}{1-\overline{w}z}.$$
Then $|g(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$, so $g$ must have a zero in the unit disk, i.e. $f(z)=w$ for some $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g\equiv -t$ ($t\in\mathbb{C}, 0\le|t|<1$). By Rouchè's theorem, we know that the number of zeros of $f+g_t$ are the same since $|f(z)|>|t|$ for all $|z|=1$. Therefore, it suffice to prove that there exists some $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)<1$ and put $g\equiv -f(z_0)$ to conclude.